# nexus-prisma with jest: running tests error

Tags: jestjs, nexus-prisma

I am using prisma with nexus-prisma and I am trying to run tests. Without success. My package.json.

Thanks for your help!

```
"@prisma/client": "^2.30.1",
"nexus": "^1.1.0",
"nexus-prisma": "^0.33.0",
"jest": "^27.1.0"

  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "dotenv/config"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./src/test/jest-setup.ts"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "\\.tsx?$": [
        "babel-jest",
        {
          "configFile": "./.babelrc.jest.js"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

[image]